# Javascript POST data corrupted in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm sending a request through AJAX but noticed the data being corrupted when I read in the server.

Java script data:-

THis is the JSON stringify object.

```
gen_points ==  {"0":[{"x_axis":"0.65","y_axis":"07/09/2016 03:59","point":"239","callout":"","y_axis_position":"","x_axis_position":"","callout_box_color":"AB2567","draw_type":"Box","height":"","width":"","angle":""}]}
```

Server data:-

```
alldata = request.POST
print 'Store Callouts == ', alldata
Store Callouts ==  <QueryDict: {u'0[0][height]': [u''], u'0[0][angle]': [u''], u'0[0][y_axis_position]': [u''], u'0[0][x_axis_position]': [u''], u'0[0][point]': [u'239'], u'0[0][y_axis]': [u'07/09/2016 03:59'], u'0[0][width]': [u''], u'0[0][callout]': [u''], u'0[0][draw_type]': [u'Box'], u'0[0][callout_box_color]': [u'AB2567'], u'0[0][x_axis]': [u'0.65']}>
```

Not sure why the data is totally different.

Here is my request.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/store-callouts/?' + 'report_name=' + $('#report_names').val() + '&report_run_date=' + $('#report_dates').val() +  '&report_num=' + report_num ,            
                type: 'POST',            
                data: gen_points,
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result.status == 'success') {
                        alert('comments updated')
                        console.log('chart results == ', result)
                    } else if (result.status == 'session timeout') {
                        alert("Session expired -- Please relogin")
                        document.location.href = "/";
                    } else {
                        alert("Unable to get data!! Contact Support");
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Call to charts data failed");
                }
            })
```

Answer:-

This issue has been resolved after I added JSON.stringify(gen_points) .

Comment: How are you doing your request?

Comment: Added the javascript request

Comment: After I added JSON.stringify(gen_points) it works..

Comment: If you add that as an answer, you can accept it to show that it’s your solution in this case.